# Socket and node.js send

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to update a position on a google map using socket.io and node.js
I have 2 different ways of updating the map. Probably some basic issue as I'm new to this.

1) Using a API call that works that looks like this:

app.post('/location', function(request, response) {

```
var obj = request.body;
//var obj = { gps_latitude: '59.33535', gps_heading: '0.0', gps_timestamp: '1397132411524', gps_speed: '0.0', device_id: 'oscar', gps_longitude: '17.999672099999998' };
//insertLocation(obj);
console.log("Connected clients: " + map_clients.length);

for(var i=0; i < map_clients.length; i++){
  var client = map_clients[i];
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify({ type:'gps', data:obj});
  console.log(jsonString);
  client.send(jsonString);
}

response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("OK");
response.end();
});
```

2) Updating using socket from a client this dont work?
Server code looks like:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function(client){ 
map_clients.push(client);
//Update position  
client.on('position', function (data) {
    var obj = { gps_latitude: '59.33535', gps_heading: '0.0', gps_timestamp: '1397132411524', gps_speed: '0.0', device_id: 'oscar', gps_longitude: '17.999672099999998' };
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify({ type:'gps', data:obj});
    console.log(jsonString);
    client.send(jsonString);         
});
client.on('disconnect', function(){
map_clients.splice(map_clients.indexOf(client), 1);
})
});
```

I can see that it send the data in the console:

debug - websocket writing 3:::{"type":"gps","data":{"gps_latitude":"59.33535","gps_heading":"0.0","gps_timestamp":"1397132411524","gps_speed":"0.0","device_id":"oscar","gps_longitude":"17.999672099999998"}}

But the map dont get updated. On the map client side i have this code but never gets triggered when i try tpo update through socket code above.

```
socket = io.connect(socket_url);

  socket.on('message', function(d){
    console.log("update position");
    var parsedObj = JSON.parse(d);
    if(parsedObj.type === 'gps'){
      var gps = parsedObj.data;
      $('#messages').append(formatGPSHTMLOutput(gps));
      processGPS(gps);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
client.emit('position', {your:"jsondata"})
```

instead of client.send, if you use

```
client.on('position', callback)
```

on the server side, you also need to use

```
socket.on('position', callback)
```

on the client side

Comment: Hmm now I'm not really following.
I have 2 client side pages.
1) thats sends its position.
2) That gets the position through server from page 1.

On page 1 to send position i have:
function initSocket(){
      socket = io.connect(socket_url);
 socket.emit('position', { gps_latitude: '59.33535', gps_heading: '0.0', gps_timestamp: '1397132411524', gps_speed: '0.0', device_id: 'oscar', gps_longitude: '17.999672099999998'});
    console.log('Send position');
    }

And that executes the script on the server. But the connection betwwen server and page 2 dont seem to work.